# AddInOrder Best Structure? Java homework

Tags: java, structure

Currently I have a problem where I have a list of IDs, each with a related score.

For example:

**ID : SCORE**

1 : 12

2 : 15

3 : 2

4 : 99

I want to loop over these and add them to a structure in decending order of score. So the output will look something like

{4,2,1,3}

What is the best way of doing this in Java? A queue?

Thanks
Philip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a great time to learn the `Comparable` interface.  You could make a Class that compares by `score` and prints its `id` when `toString()` is called.  As mentioned earlier, using a custom `Comparator` would also suffice, but if you've never worked with `Comparable` I recommend learning that first.

Here's a link to the JavaDoc:  http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

You should know that for two objects o1 and o2 of type `Comparable<T>`, `o1.compareTo(o2)` will return:

- -1 if o1 < o2 (in the ordering defined by T, the type of o1 and o2)
- 0 if o1 == o2 (again, in the ordering, not necessarily object equality)
- 1 if o1 > o2

This information will help you write your `compareTo` function in your custom class.

Once you have your class written, then Java's `Collections` class provides a `sort` method that will sort a `List` of `Comparables`.  Easy!

Here's the link for that:  http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29

Answer (score 2):

Isn't `Collection.sort(list, comparator)` appropriate?

(`comparator` is a class implementing `Comparator` and specifying the comparison logic)

(alternatively, your class may implement the `Comparable` interface to provide the comparison logic internally)

It is not "AddInOrder", but it fulfills your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options here.  Sorting the list at the end might suffice for your purposes.

If you want to ensure that the order invariant holds all the time, then a sorted list/tree is the way to go.  Java provides a [PriorityQueue](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) class.

However, as an implementation detail, you would need to create a class to encapsulate both the `ID` and the `Score`, and have the class be comparable with respect to your particular sorting choice.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the items one by one into a sorted set (like [a tree set](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)). Use a class to hold id:score, and write a comparator which compares two instances of this classes based on their score.

EDIT: Saw that you already have the list, in this case sorting the collection is better.

Comment: Be aware, that a set forbids multiple identical elements.  It might be OK here.